# Filemanager API

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

Does somebody knows, if there is such an API for the filemanager. Just simple upload a file (simply as `base64_encode(file_get_contents())`) not via a form.

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need the [**ExpressionEngine Add-On Development docs**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html).

Comment: Yes, but im afraid there is not such an api for this subject. Hope this will come in further releases of EE.

Comment: Did you see the File Field Class?

Comment: Yes, but thats a class for the frontend and not an API like the other apis (channel/entry/category/fieldtype).